# Cannot input File to FileList angular4

Tags: angular

I have a problem with my uploadPhoto feature.The problem is I have a common component work like a library because I use angular 4 for this project.And I use ng2-cropper-img for crop file. When I handle code in my Croppep-img component I want to pass data to common component use FileList.
   Here is my code in cropper component:

```
const base64ToInputFile = this.Base64toInputFile(this.data1.image.split(',')[1]);
const imageFile = new File([base64ToInputFile],this.imgLink[0].name,{type: 'image/jpeg'});
this.activeModal.close(imageFile)
```

Now I want to transfer data to upload component with a FileList, Because When I transfer data as my File type then It's not working.Here is my code at upload component

```
fileChange(files) {
    if (this.cropImage && !this.multiple) {
      // this.fileChangeUpload(files)
      let modalRef = this.modalService.open(CropImageComponent)
      modalRef.componentInstance.imgLink = files;
      modalRef.result.then(data => {
        if (data) {
          this.fileChangeUpload(data)
        }
      })
    } else {
      this.fileChangeUpload(files)
    }
  }
```

The parameter When I catch a event files is a FileList, and angular I can't find a method to add File to FileList like broswer.I very happy if someone give me a solutions, tks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I just file a solution, when I pass data to cropper component then I take a data I receive like this

```
fileChange(files) {
    if (this.cropImage) {
      // this.fileChangeUpload(files)
      let modalRef = this.modalService.open(CropImageComponent, {backdrop: 'static'})
      modalRef.componentInstance.imgLink = files[0];
      modalRef.result.then(file => {
        if (file) {
          this.fileChangeUpload([file])
        }
      })
    } else {
      this.fileChangeUpload(files)
    }
  }
```